# Best way to update single passed as props to multiple component hierarchy at the same time in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have 3 component say `ParentComponent` , `MiddleComponent` and `ChildComponent`. ParentComponent has a  `boolean var` say `isPresent`. It is being passed as props to `MiddleComponent` which passes the var `isPresent` to the `ChildComponent`.

In this `ChildComponent`, I am doing calculation and changing value of `isPresent`. Had it been only one component, I would have used `useEffect()` but it is just the value that is being changed and I need to update the same in `ChildComponent` and `ParentComponent` and not in `MiddleComponent`. I do not want to use Virtual DOM and using temporary state might not be the solution as there is hierarchy of Components and later it might cause issues once it gets complex.

Is there a way to use the same variable **`isPresent`** and update in `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent` at the same time? It works perfectly fine if I refresh the page as updated value is being fetched from DB directly.

Comment: I think the question is self explanatory and it does not require sample code to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with a state management library like Redux to store application wide states. Your components can access and modify this state using actions and reducers. When a state is updated, all the connected components will be notified and receive the updated values.

Comment: even for 1 variable? Other parameters are not impacted. That is why I asked.

Comment: useContext hook is also a good choice as @chala-megersa mentioned its easier to implement, but not as scalable

Comment: scalablity is not the problem. as it is for only 1 vriable.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the state management library you can use context hook to achieve this.